# DBD::ODBC package for fedora 17

Tags: perl, odbc, unixodbc, fedora16

DBD::ODBC package is not available in repo. How to install the  DBD::ODBC in fedora 17?.

How to achieve the ODBC DB connectivity using DBI->connect () module.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your OS vendor's repo is always a nice convenience, but hardly comprehensive.  Get everything else from CPAN.

Also, when using ODBC on a *nix box, your 1st step is to configure your ODBC data source according to your ODBC driver's documentation.  Then provided you've set up ODBC & your Environment correctly, connecting from perl is trivial, your connect string would be `"dbi:ODBC:$DSN"`